# Context manager, multiple function calls and transactions

Tags: python, database, oracle

Say I do:

```
with my_connection:
    o.first_call()
```

where `my_connection`'s `__exit__` method calls for a rollback

and `o.first_call` in its execution calls `j.second_call`, which itself calls `z.third_call`. Say that `z.third_call` successfully inserted a record in to a database, `j.second_call` also successfully inserts a record, but `o.first_call` craps out. Will I get a rollback back to the state before I first entered the context of my_connection or will I get rollbacked to a state between `o.first_call` and `j.second_call`?

EDIT: To be clear, I'm hoping that the entire thing gets rolled back to before I ever called `o.first_call`

EDIT2: I'm hoping if there was some magic I could do in the `__enter__`, some kind of context to say, look whatever is called is one big transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions will be rolled-back to the last `commit` call.

Per [Database API Specification v2.0](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rollback):

> .commit()
>
> Commit any pending transaction to the database.
>
> .rollback()
>
> ... causes the database to roll back to the start of any 
>   pending transaction.

So it depends on what you mean by "successfully inserted". If the insertion was finalized with a call to `commit`, then the rollback will not remove the insertion. However, if there was no commit, then the insertion will get rolled-back.

Comment: But say `j.second_call` commits after its successful insertion, then  `o.first_call`'s rollback will bring me back in a wrong place. How can I make the entire thing a transaction?

Comment: Don't call commit after `j.second_call()`.

Comment: Right, but I was hoping if there was some magic I could do in the `__enter__`, some kind of context to say, look whatever is called is one big transaction.

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists, short of saving a copy of the database files in `__enter__`, then in `__exit__` shutting down the server, replacing the database files, and restarting the server. That is so incredibly ugly... I'm not suggesting doing that! -- but that is what it would take to revert a commit. The solution is to not call `commit` until you are sure the transaction should be committed.

Comment: What about setting some kind of context on the db side, could such a thing exist?

Comment: What DB server are you using?

Comment: Oracle sitting on redhat.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle, so I'm not the best person to answer this. All I can say is I'm not aware of such a thing. (And if such a thing exists, it is server-specific, since there is no mention of it in [Python Database Specification](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rollback)).